# Core dump at Gazebo startup

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try the following terminal command.

*roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch*

I get the following error

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

[empty_world_server-1] process has died [pid 3395, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/chartoin/.ros/log/26f27722-9b42-11e1-b127-3859f9dbd9aa/empty_world_server-1.log].

log file: /home/chartoin/.ros/log/26f27722-9b42-11e1-b127-3859f9dbd9aa/empty_world_server-1*.log

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  3406 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so

[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 3403, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/chartoin/.ros/log/26f27722-9b42-11e1-b127-3859f9dbd9aa/gazebo_gui-2.log].

log file: /home/chartoin/.ros/log/26f27722-9b42-11e1-b127-3859f9dbd9aa/gazebo_gui-2*.log

This error happens on a Thinkpad x120e laptop with an AMD Fushion e 350 APU. The same command works well when I use a Dell XPS 15 laptop with intel processor and nvidia graphics card.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33763/core-dump-at-gazebo-startup/) by [Charuvahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2214/charuvahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2012-06-07**:
I get this on a Ubuntu 12.04 system and Nvidia graphics card (GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1) using the 64-bit 295.41 dev drivers).  But it works on my 12.04 laptop with an AMD card  (ATI RV730 XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670 ).  Update - no it crashes the same way after a few minutes.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2012-06-07**:
I get this on a Ubuntu 12.04 system and Nvidia graphics card (GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1) using the 64-bit 295.41 dev drivers).

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-06-12**:
@lucasw do you think it's got to do with the drivers? been following the issue on this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/33449/gazebo-illegal-instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the same Error with Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and ROS Fuerte.
On the same laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and ROS Electric everything works like a charm, so if there have not been any major changes to the graphics driver in Ubuntu 12.04 I would say it's a problem with gazebo.

As stated in this thread [Klick](http://answers.ros.org/question/33449/gazebo-illegal-instruction) it may relate to issues with gazebo which should be solved with an update, but my system is up-to-date and I still get the same error.

Update:

Created an remastered Ubuntu distribution with ROS and everything of my current system. When I boot from live usb stick and run gazebo on my second notebook (Intel graphics card) everything is just fine...
So perhaps back to an hardware issue.

---

Originally posted by [Chade](https://answers.ros.org/users/2805/chade/) with karma: 16 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0